# Conexion a SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de hacer una conexión desde mi proyecto local a una base de datos SQL que hice y subi a un servidor, el servidor me da la conexion string que hay que usar, pero cuando uso el open me tira error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("workstation id=BDInstant.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=XXXXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXX;data source=BDInstant.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=BDInstant");
cn.Open();
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Parece un problema de redes y no de programación. Es probable que un cortafuegos no permita el acceso al puerto del servidor. ¿Has intentado hacer un telnet al servidor en el puerto en que escucha el SQL? ¿Te puedes conectar desde el management studio?

Comment: Podrías aclarar sobre que herramientas y/o lenguaje/s (y librerías/frameworks si aplica) estás intentando realizando la conexión.

Comment: El servidor es somee, dudo que no tengan bien configurado SQL

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti, utiliza la notación arroba+usuario para que el sistema notifique al usuario al que respondes. Supongo que me respondías a mi, y la verdad, no he dicho que ellos no tengan bien configurado el SQL. Sin embargo, no respondes a mis preguntas.

Comment: @jachguate Disculpa, no probé hacer un Telnet al servidor, tampoco desde el Management Studio ya que no lo utilice. Ejecutando el proyecto localmente no me deja usar la conexión a SQL Server por eso error, si me dejo cuando subí el proyecto al servidor, con eso pude solucionarlo aunque es un poco mas difícil para debuguear, lo raro es que vi tutoriales acerca de ese servidor donde si se podían conectar al server SQL Server localmente, pero bueno, tal vez lo habrán cambiado

Comment: Bien, pues prueba hacer un telnet, si funciona (que lo dudo), prueba conectarte via Management studio y comenta aquí el resultado de tus pruebas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El servidor no tenia permisos para acceder a la base de datos desde nuestra PC Local, para poder ejecutar las consultas primero debemos subir nuestro proyecto a su servidor